# Tagging CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, styled-components

Recently, when I was creating a global styles file, I discovered that is possible to avoid the two point notation(selector) replacing it by brackets and it works as expected. Something like that.:

```
:focus {
  // some css styles here
}

===

[focus] {
  // some css styles here
}
```

Talking about selectors that has double two point notation(like ::selection), how can I get the same approach using only brackets to this, as in the example above?

```
::selection {
   // some css styles here
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced you can replace `:focus` with `[focus]`. (That latter syntax has a different purpose.) Do you have a demo that shows them both working the same way? Anyhow, why would you want a replacement for `::selection`? It works as is!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: This isn't "tagging", that is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). You tagged this with `style-components`, so most likely when an element _gets_ the focus, your library _sets_ a `focus` attribute on the element, which will make this selector work for focussed elements then.